# Prototype invoke and replace functions together

Tags: prototype, replace, invoke

sorry for this silly question.
I want to bind .invoke and .replace prototype functions.
Originally I have:

```
$('#element').replace(output + '...');
```

But I need to relate it to a class element, so I use invoke like:

```
$$('.element').invoke('replace', output + '...');
```

This is wrong, what's the correct syntax ?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you have for the second is correct and should do what you require, however the syntax for the first is wrong. It should be:

```
$('element').replace(output + '...');
```

The $() function takes an ID without the leading #.